# Sqlite fetch a particular value not present within the specified limit

Tags: sqlite

I have a table Customer which has the following columns,

```
user_name,current_id,id,params,display,store.
```

I am writing a query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE user_name='Mike' AND current_id='9845' AND id='Get_Owner' AND params='owner=1' order by(display) limit 6 offset 0
```

Now there are times when I want to fetch a particular value which is not there in the first six and I want to fetch that particular value and rest 5 values in the same way like above how can I do that?

For example I want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE user_name='Mike' AND current_id='9845' and id='Get_Owner' AND params='owner=1' AND stored='Shelly.Am'
```

I want Shelly.Am and other 5 value like my first query

Comment: I believe that you could make your post clearer by consistently referring to databse terms. eg I think  _...and rest 5 values...._  (which implies that there are other columns in the table)  should perhaps be_....and the 5 remaining **rows**..._

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two queries by using a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).
The ORDER BY/LIMIT clauses would apply to the entire compound query, so the second query must be moved into a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE user_name='Mike'
  AND current_id='9845'
  AND id='Get_Owner'
  AND params='owner=1'
  AND stored='Shelly.Am'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Customer
      WHERE user_name='Mike'
        AND current_id='9845'
        AND id='Get_Owner'
        AND params='owner=1'
        AND stored!='Shelly.Am'
      ORDER BY display
      LIMIT 5);
```